# How to write Lognormal Distribution using matlab

Tags: matlab

I am facing this problem.

```
Error using lognfit (line 52)
The data in X must be positive.
Error in testing (line 173)
        [a(i-100,j) b(i-100,j)] = lognfit(x);
```

My code is as follows:

```
for i = 101:401
    for j = 1:37
        x  = Gco(i-100:i,j).';
        [f,xv] = ecdf(x);
        [a(i-100,j) b(i-100,j)] = lognfit(x); % a is mu and b is sigma
```

Comment: What are you trying to do?  What is `Gco`? Give us more information about the problem you are trying to solve. Also, MATLAB's error messages are very informative.  Obviously, the data in the input parameter to `lognfit` has negative values and the function dictates that the data must be strictly positive.

Comment: I try to simulate the statistical model for RCS  (Radar Cross Section) of complex object using measurement model in ultra wideband.  Gco = 10*log10(Pco); % Pco is power signal from measurement

Comment: It is possible that `Pco < 1`, which gives you a negative result. Trying to use `lognfit` will give you that error.  As such, I'm not sure you can apply a log-normal fit to your data.  You may have to fit your model using Watts instead of dB, then when you're done convert the units back to dB.

Comment: Yes, Pco value is less than 1. How can I do? Thank you.

Comment: Is there another unit you can represent your power in?  One that is strictly positive?  If you can, fit your data using this unit (Watts perhaps).  Then when you're done, simply use this function to output your power in Watts, then convert to dB.

Comment: Okay..I convert Watts. However, I face with this problem again. Subscripted assignment dimension mismatch.

Error in testing (line 174)
        [a(i-100,j) b(i-100,j)] = lognfit(x); I declare a and b is as follows:a = zeros(301,37);
b = zeros(301,37);
h = zeros(301,37);

Comment: where i need to change?? i am not expert in matalab. Thank you so much  your answer..rayryeng

Comment: Please edit your post with this new code